# Vue.js .toLowerCase() is not a fucntion

Tags: vue.js, axios

Im new to vue.js.

I was wondering if someone could tell me where i am going wrong.

Im trying to get my values in my data to come out in lowercase but i keep getting the error below.

vue:6 TypeError: players.nat.toLowerCase is not a function

This is my HTML:

```
<img class="player-nat-flag" v-bind:src="'https://assets.ocs-sport.com/flags/svg/flag_' + players.nat.toLowerCase() + '.svg'">
```

This is my Vue.js code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            searchQuery: null,
            info: null,
            loading: true,
            errored: false
        }
    },
    mounted () {
    axios
      .get('')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data.player
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    },
    computed: {
        resultQuery(){
              if(this.searchQuery){
              return this.info.filter((players)=>{
                return this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => players.full_name.toLowerCase().includes(v))
              })
              }else{
                return this.info;
              }
        },
        info(){
              return this.info.filter((players)=>{
                return this.info.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => players.nat.toLowerCase().includes(v))
              })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You have `players.nat.toLowerCase()` in your template and no `players` in `data` or `computed`. What you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `players` is not a variable in your data or your computed variable. Therefore it will not be available in your HTML template.

Try adding something like this:

```js
...
computed: {
    players() {
        // get your player data here
        let response = this.foo();
        return response;
    }
}
...
```

This way `players` would be available in your HTML tmeplate